# regex, avoid a line, if a word occurs in it

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find certain lines in which "like" comes before the word "crusegdf". For example, given the following input:

```
def shared temp-table w-cruseg no-undo field cruise-id like crusegdf.segment-id
define {1} shared temp-table tt-history no-undo like crusegdf.
```

I only want to match the second line. But my regex finds both these lines. The regex that I use now is:

```
(?i)(define|def)(.*?)(temp-table)(.*?)(like)\s*(\bcrusegdf\b)\s*(\.)
```

Comment: *Negative lookbehind*?

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: I'm not sure that a regex is the best way to parse that data if you could have a "field" with a value of "like" and a "like" with a value of "field".

Comment: I doubt that lazy dot matching is appropriate when you match blocks of text  that should contain some specific text inside. Use an unrolled tempered greedy token.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `\b` to delimit your field name, because your input has field names that contain dots; the dot is not a "word" character.

Instead use a negative look ahead for a dot then more field name:

```
^(?i)(define|def).*?temp-table.*?like\s*\bcrusegdf\b(?!\.\w).*$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/RUeoZMFs1l).

I also removed the unnecessary brackets (your question did not say you needed to capture input).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually i want it the way i mentioned. It is a special case, and i have not mentioned all the conditions as there are a lot. I need to find both cases using two different regex. One with 'field' in the line and the other without 'field' in line. All other brackets are also required as i am capturing those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookahead regex for matching a like containing `like` that doesn't contain `define` before it:

```
^(?:(?!\bfield\b).)*like.*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY3nU2/2)

`(?:(?!\bfield\b).)*` will match 0 or more any characters that doesn't have `field` at next position.

Comment: i also need to make sure that the word 'temp-table' is in the line. How can i do so?

Comment: In that case use: `^(?=.*temp-table)(?:(?!\bfield\b).)*like.*`